# How to execute a SQL script using dbExpress?

Tags: delphi, dbexpress

I'm migrating an old Delphi application (using ZeosDB) to Delphi XE2. I want to use dbExpress as a ZeosDB replacement for database access to Firebird 2.5 or MS-SQL.
There are a lot of sql scripts for creating tables, view and stored procedures I need to run. The Firebird script commands are seperated with ^, MS-SQL script commands with "GO".

How can I run these scripts on the database using a dbexpress connection? ZeosDB provides a TZSqlProcessor, but I can't find any equivalent component for dbExpress.

Comment: spare yourself a lot of headaches and use a third party commercial component suit, just my two cents...

Comment: Just an ironic thing to point out: In Delphi XE2 (and some other newer versions), the tab where all the ADO components are found is labeled "dbGo" yet nothing in there (that I'm aware of) supports using the `GO` statement...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not use DBExpress but as far as I am aware, you can execute (either by Execute or ExecuteDirect) only one SQL command at a time. In other words you cannot put the whole script into the Execute method.

This is not related to different command syntax used by FireBird and MS SQL (^ vs. GO). You have to understand the '^' sign or 'GO' command is not a "TSQL Command"! Both are specific command delimiters used by respective application used to execute commands against the SQL engines. Instead it is difference between "Firebird Manager" (or how it's called) and "SQL Query Profiler" (or "SQL Server Management Studio").

The solution is to use some kind of parser, split the script into a list of single commands, and TSQLConnection.Execute these commands one-by-one.

Something like this pseudocode:

```
var
  DelimiterPos: Integer;
  S: String;
  Command: String;
begin
  S:= ScriptFile; // ScriptFile: String - your whole script
  While True Do
  begin
    DelimiterPos:= Pos('^', ScriptFile);
    if DelimiterPos = 0 then DelimiterPos:= Length(S);
    Command:= Copy(S, 1, DelimiterPos - 1);
    SQLConnection.Execute(Command);
    Delete(S, 1, DelimiterPos);
    if Lengh(S) = 0 Then Exit;
  end;
end;
```

Please note that the sample above will work correctly only in cases that the '^' sign is not used anywhere in the script but a command separator.

As a sidenote, I am sure there are some already built components that will do that for you (like TZSQLProcessor). I am not aware of any to point you to.

Sidenote 2: I am pretty sure, that you'll have to modify your scripts to be fully compatible with MS SQL. Eventhough Firebird and MS SQL are both SQL servers there is always difference in DML/DDL syntax.

**Edit:**

1. If you can "rewrite" the SQL script into the code, you could use Jedi VCL jvStringHolder component. Put each separate command as one item (of type TStrings) in [jvStringHolder](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help%3aJvStringHolder.pas).
2. Creating the parser is rather complicated, but not undoable. With the inspiration from SynEdit i made these clases to exactly what you need: Load the script with TSQLScript.ParseScript, then iterate through Command[index: integer] property. The SQLLexer is not full SQL Lexer, but implements keywords separation with respec to comments, brackets, code folding etc. I've also added a special syntax into comments ($ sign in comment block) that helps me put titles into the script.
   This is full copy-paste from one of my projects. I'm not giving any more explanation, but I hope you can get the idea and make it running in your project.

unit SQLParser;

```
interface

type

  TTokenKind = (tkUknown, tkEOF, tkComment, tkKeyword, tkIdentifier,
                tkCommentParam, tkCommentParamValue, tkCommandEnd, tkCRLF);

  TBlockKind = (bkNone, bkLineComment, bkBlockComment);

  TSQLLexer = class
  private
    FBlockKind: TBlockKind;
    FParseString: String;
    FPosition: PChar;
    FTokenKind: TTokenKind;
    FTokenPosition: PChar;
    function GetToken: String;
    procedure Reset;
    procedure SetParseString(Value: String);
  protected
    procedure ReadComment;
    procedure ReadCommentParam;
    procedure ReadCommentParamValue;
    procedure ReadCRLF;
    procedure ReadIdentifier;
    procedure ReadSpace;
  public
    constructor Create(ParseString: String);
    function NextToken: TTokenKind;

    property Position: PChar read FPosition;
    property SQLText: String read FParseString write SetParseString;
    property Token: String read GetToken;
    property TokenKind: TTokenKind read FTokenKind;
    property TokenPosition: PChar read FTokenPosition;
  end;



implementation

uses SysUtils;

{ TSQLLexer }

constructor TSQLLexer.Create(ParseString: string);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FParseString:= ParseString;
  Reset;
end;

function TSQLLexer.GetToken;
begin
  SetString(Result, FTokenPosition, FPosition - FTokenPosition);
end;

function TSQLLexer.NextToken: TTokenKind;
begin
  case FBlockKind of
    bkLineComment, bkBlockComment: ReadComment;
    else
      case FPosition^ of
      #0: FTokenKind:= tkEOF;
      #1..#9, #11, #12, #14..#32:
        begin
          ReadSpace;
          NextToken;
        end;
      #10, #13: ReadCRLF;
      '-':
        if PChar(FPosition +1)^ = '-' then
          ReadComment
        else
          Inc(FPosition);
      '/':
        if PChar(FPosition +1)^ = '*' then
          ReadComment
        else
          Inc(FPosition);
      'a'..'z', 'A'..'Z': ReadIdentifier;
      ';':
        begin
          FTokenPosition:= FPosition;
          Inc(FPosition);
          FTokenKind:= tkCommandEnd;
        end
      else
        Inc(FPosition);
      end;
  end;
  Result:= FTokenKind;
end;


procedure TSQLLexer.ReadComment;
begin
  FTokenPosition:= FPosition;
  if not (FBlockKind in [bkLineComment, bkBlockComment])  then
  begin
    if FPosition^ = '/' then
      FBlockKind:= bkBlockComment
    else
      FBlockKind:= bkLineComment;
    Inc(FPosition, 2);
  end;
  case FPosition^ of
    '$': ReadCommentParam;
    ':': ReadCommentParamValue;
  else
    while not CharInSet(FPosition^, [#0, '$']) do
    begin
      if FBlockKind = bkBlockComment then
      begin
        if (FPosition^ = '*') And (PChar(FPosition + 1)^ = '/') then
        begin
          Inc(FPosition, 2);
          FBlockKind:= bkNone;
          Break;
        end;
      end
      else
      begin
        if CharInSet(Fposition^, [#10, #13]) then
        begin
          ReadCRLF;
          FBlockKind:= bkNone;
          Break;
        end;
      end;
      Inc(FPosition);
    end;
    FTokenKind:= tkComment;
  end;
end;

procedure TSQLLexer.ReadCommentParam;
begin
  Inc(FPosition);
  ReadIdentifier;
  FTokenKind:= tkCommentParam;
end;

procedure TSQLLexer.ReadCommentParamValue;
begin
  Inc(FPosition);
  ReadSpace;
  FTokenPosition:= FPosition;
  while not CharInSet(FPosition^, [#0, #10, #13]) do
    Inc(FPosition);
  FTokenKind:= tkCommentParamValue;
end;

procedure TSQLLexer.ReadCRLF;
begin
  while CharInSet(FPosition^, [#10, #13]) do
    Inc(FPosition);
  FTokenKind:= tkCRLF;
end;

procedure TSQLLexer.ReadIdentifier;
begin
  FTokenPosition:= FPosition;
  while CharInSet(FPosition^, ['a'..'z', 'A'..'Z', '_']) do
    Inc(FPosition);

  FTokenKind:= tkIdentifier;

  if Token = 'GO' then
    FTokenKind:= tkKeyword;
end;

procedure TSQLLexer.ReadSpace;
begin
  while CharInSet(FPosition^, [#1..#9, #11, #12, #14..#32]) do
  Inc(FPosition);
end;

procedure TSQLLexer.Reset;
begin
  FTokenPosition:= PChar(FParseString);
  FPosition:= FTokenPosition;
  FTokenKind:= tkUknown;
  FBlockKind:= bkNone;
end;

procedure TSQLLexer.SetParseString(Value: String);
begin
  FParseString:= Value;
  Reset;
end;

end.
```

The parser:

```
type
  TScriptCommand = class
  private
    FCommandText: String;
  public
    constructor Create(ACommand: String);
    property CommandText: String read FCommandText write FCommandText;
  end;

  TSQLScript = class
  private
    FCommands: TStringList;
    function GetCount: Integer;
    function GetCommandList: TStrings;
    function GetCommand(index: Integer): TScriptCommand;
  protected
    procedure AddCommand(AName: String; ACommand: String);
  public
    Constructor Create;
    Destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure ParseScript(Script: TStrings);

    property Count: Integer read GetCount;
    property CommandList: TStrings read GetCommandList;
    property Command[index: integer]: TScriptCommand read GetCommand;
  end;

{ TSQLScriptCommand }

constructor TScriptCommand.Create(ACommand: string);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FCommandText:= ACommand;
end;

{ TSQLSCript }

constructor TSQLScript.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FCommands:= TStringList.Create(True);
  FCommands.Duplicates:= dupIgnore;
  FCommands.Sorted:= False;
end;

destructor TSQLScript.Destroy;
begin
  FCommands.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TSQLScript.AddCommand(AName, ACommand: String);
var
  ScriptCommand: TScriptCommand;
  S: String;
begin
  if AName = '' then
    S:= SUnnamedCommand
  else
    S:= AName;
  ScriptCommand:= TScriptCommand.Create(ACommand);
  FCommands.AddObject(S, ScriptCommand);
end;

function TSQLScript.GetCommand(index: Integer): TScriptCommand;
begin
  Result:= TScriptCommand(FCommands.Objects[index]);
end;

function TSQLScript.GetCommandList: TStrings;
begin
  Result:= FCommands;
end;

function TSQLScript.GetCount: Integer;
begin
  Result:= FCommands.Count;
end;

procedure TSQLScript.ParseScript(Script: TStrings);
var
  Title: String;
  Command: String;
  LastParam: String;
  LineParser: TSQLLexer;
  IsNewLine: Boolean;
  LastPos: PChar;

  procedure AppendCommand;
  var
    S: String;
  begin
    SetString(S, LastPos, LineParser.Position - LastPos);
    Command:= Command + S;
    LastPos:= LineParser.Position;
  end;

  procedure FinishCommand;
  begin
    if Command <> '' then
      AddCommand(Title, Command);
    Title:= '';
    Command:= '';
    LastPos:= LineParser.Position;
    if LastPos^ = ';' then Inc(LastPos);
  end;

begin
  LineParser:= TSQLLexer.Create(Script.Text);
  try
    LastPos:= LineParser.Position;
    IsNewLine:= True;
    repeat
      LineParser.NextToken;
      case LineParser.TokenKind of
        tkComment: LastPos:= LineParser.Position;
        tkCommentParam:
          begin
            LastParam:= UpperCase(LineParser.Token);
            LastPos:= LineParser.Position;
          end;
        tkCommentParamValue:
          if LastParam = 'TITLE' then
          begin
            Title:= LineParser.Token;
            LastParam:= '';
            LastPos:= LineParser.Position;
          end;
        tkKeyword:
            if (LineParser.Token = 'GO') and IsNewLine then FinishCommand
            else
              AppendCommand;
        tkEOF:
          FinishCommand;
        else
          AppendCommand;
      end;
      IsNewLine:= LineParser.TokenKind in [tkCRLF, tkCommandEnd];
    until LineParser.TokenKind = tkEOF;
  finally
    LineParser.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Can someone point me to a good sql script processor? I can't understand why embarcadero has forget to implement such an important feature.

Comment: Second comment: Writing a parser is much more complicated. For the GO keyword, you have to write a tokenizer and check for some syntax rules to prevent mismatches like CREATE .. -- MY GO COMMENT or INSERT ... 'GO FOO BAR'. You have to check for literals, comments etc. The scripts must be compatible to the coresponding database utilities, so just replacing GO with ^ or something else isn't a solution.

Comment: I too wrote a SQL parser as everyone else has already described.  I use 'GO' on a single line to signal the parser to execute everything since the 'last GO'.  You can easily check for 'GO' as a single string like this: `if SameText(Trim(OneLineOfSQL), 'GO') then ExecuteSQLStatement;`.

Comment: +1 I spent about 4 days building something similar to be able to split an MSSQL script with `GO`. That was when I was still learning though...

Comment: One project of mine I actually built a library in Delphi which automatically makes sure all database structure is up to date, and the SQL scripts were built-in to the application. It even recognizes the version and builds the database accordingly. The library is used in our software's update application. This library also became useful for other tasks in the much larger project it was designed for. Unfortunately this project requires a whole new approach which I'm not sure if you're willing to shift to. However it can prove to be a great advantage too.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `TSQLConnection`. This is component have a two methods, `Execute` and `ExecuteDirect`. The first does not accept parameters, but the second method does.

Using the first method:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   MeuSQL: String;
begin
   MeuSQL := 'INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE ('FIELD1', 'FIELD2') VALUES ('VALUE1', 'VALUE2')';
   SQLConnection.ExecuteDirect(MeuSQL);
end;
```

If you want, you can  use a transaction.

Using the second method:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MySQL: string;
  MyParams: TParams;
begin
  MySQL := 'INSERT INTO TABLE ("FIELD1", "FIELD2") VALUE (:PARAM1, :PARAM2)';
  MyParams.Create;
  MyParams.CreateParam(ftString, 'PARAM1', ptInput).Value := 'Seu valor1';
  MyParams.CreateParam(ftString, 'PARAM2', ptInput).Value := 'Seu valor2';

  SQLConnection1.Execute(MySQL,MyParams, Nil);
end;
```

Comment: [...]for creating tables, view and stored procedures[...] from a SQL script file. Your answer has no releation to the question!

Comment: Of course it has. My colleague wanted to know which component to use to run scripts and what was spent. The TSQLConnection is the best component to do this. However, you can also use the TStoredProc to connect or run scripts Stored Procedures.

Comment: How to construct SQL statement for second scenario in case I want to use "order by" clause?

Answer (score 1):

I am about 90% sure that you can't, at least not without parsing the individual commands between the GO's, and then serially executing each of them, which as you have already pointed out, is problematic.

(I would be happy to be disproved on the above, and quite interested in seeing the solution...)

If you are simply using the script as initialisation logic (e.g. to create tables, etc), another solution you could consider would be to fire off the scripts in a batch file and executing them via 'Sqlcmd', which could be executed via your delphi app (using ShellExecute), which then waits for it to complete before continuing.

Not as elegant as using a component, but if it is just for initialisation logic it may be a quick, acceptable compromise.  I certainly wouldn't consider the above for any processing post-initialisation.

Comment: Our company found it extremely useful to use OSQL from batch files. It's rather easy, one command may look like `OSQL -Usa -P MyPass -S MyServer -d MyDatabase -i MySQLScript.sql -o MyOutputFile.txt` (on an MSSQL database)

Comment: Hi Jerry, yes that is exactly what I was referring to, except of course that SqlCmd has superceded osql.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't appear to be a dbExpress limitation, but a SQL language limitation. I'm not sure about T-SQL, but it seems like the GO is similar to an anonymous block in Oracle PL/SQL. You can put the following PL/SQL code in the TSqlDataSet.CommandText and call ExecSQL to create multiple tables. Maybe T-SQL has a similar way to do this:

```
begin
execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE suppliers 
( supplier_id number(10) not null, 
  supplier_name varchar2(50) not null, 
  contact_name varchar2(50)  
)'; 
execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE customers 
( customer_id number(10) not null, 
  customer_name varchar2(50) not null, 
  address varchar2(50),  
  city varchar2(50),  
  state varchar2(25),  
  zip_code varchar2(10),  
  CONSTRAINT customers_pk PRIMARY KEY (customer_id) 
)';
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how often you need to create those tables, but how about putting all separate SQL create scripts in a table, with sequential/version numbering?
Than you can go through that table and execute 'm one by one.
You'll need to split your scripts once, but after that it's much more maintainable.